# Change default arrow in expand/collapse nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, bootstrap-4

I want to change the arrow pointing down in the following code using fontawsome fonts. I am not sure what should I do to:

1- make the default arrow on the right of the parent node disappear.

2- to use "+/-" signs to indicate collapse state.

Clearly the onclick code is not working correctly.

Currently the following code shows `+ Parent Node >`

When I click on "+" sign, the list is expanded and the "+" sign is replaced by empty square instead of "-" sign.

```
<a href="#homeSubmenu" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
   onclick="$('#AAA').toggleClass('fas fa fa-minus')">

<i class="fas fa fa-plus" id="AAA"></i>
   Parent Node
</a>

<ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Sub Node 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Sub Node 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could force the dropdown arrow to disappear:

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
   display: none;
}
```

**UPDATE**
To change your icon, change your `onclick` to have this:

`$('#AAA').toggleClass('fa-minus fa-plus')`

Comment: Thank you, this works good. Do you please have any suggestions with +/- toggle code above? Thanks.

Comment: @NoChance, I updated my answer. Sorry was a bit busy

Answer (score 1):

call toggleClass for plus sign `$('#AAA').toggleClass('fa-minus').toggleClass('fa-plus')`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#homeSubmenu" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
   onclick="$('#AAA').toggleClass('fa-minus').toggleClass('fa-plus')">

<i class="fas fa fa-plus" id="AAA"></i>
   Parent Node
</a>

<ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Sub Node 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Sub Node 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The onclick code works. Thank you. However, the code snippet above does not show the child nodes. I tried my original code with the onclick code that you have provided and it works well in JSFiddle. Maybe fontawsome is missing or some other library. Anyway, I got what I wanted thanks.

Comment: i forgot to add bootstrap js library :( i edited my answer. now it should work.

Comment: Yes it works. Together with the answer provided by @Frank Fajardo it should be all what I want. Thanks.

Comment: While your code works, the other answer was more complete as it addressed how to get rid of the default arrow. Thanks for your help, but I had to mark the other entry as answer for that.